# Webview Rendering Issue - Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView within a FrameLayout. The height and width attributes of both the views have been set to 'fill_parent'. However, when I retrieve content from a site and display it via the WebView, the site occupies only 3/4th of the height of the screen. The width of the view is fine, however. Is there some change that needs to be made on the server side or can something be done through the Android code to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us some code and perhaps the webpage you are using?  Do you have the same problem in both landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: Thanks for the response - the problem was with the site. It needed a slight tweak.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am calling a page which has extjs code. But at the time of loading it takes only 1/4th of web view.

Comment: @Brijesh - There seems to be a hack around this. But, this has to be done on the web-end of the webpage that you are trying to load. I am not sure about the precise attributes that you need to change in the web code. But it has to do something with the zoom level. I have done quite a lot of research and unfortunately you cannot do anything through Android itself for this specific case.

Comment: True. It needs to be handled on serverside. But can you name the attribute or some hint , so that I can tell server team to fix it.

Comment: @BrijeshThakur Sorry for getting back to you this late, but as far I understand, some javascript code was necessary to implement this.

Comment: Got it Fix using other mechanism , Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView displays page views at full zoom (not in "overview mode"). That is, it appears at the default size for the page, instead of zoomed out. (This is also how the page appears if the user disables overview mode.)

You can control how the page appears in a WebView by playing with the "viewport" property in an HTML  tag (which must be placed in your document ).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html for the full info.

Comment: Torid - this didn't directly solve my problem. I have forwarded it to the web developers to look into the mobile optimization for the site. But, since you have indicated valuable information that I was oblivious to, I am accepting your answer. Thank you so much, Torid

Answer (score 0):

Check for zoom level for the web view...

Comment: If I tamper with the zoom level, it changes both width and the height. However, I just want to modify the height. Thanks for the answer though. I figured out how to solve the problem - a server side tweak is needed

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am calling a page which has extjs code. But at the time of loading it takes only 1/4th of web view. Can you please tell me what server side tweak is required ?